# Threading with Parallel.For Adding Lists

Tags: .net, multithreading, thread-safety, task-parallel-library, parallel.for

I am having trouble using the Parallel.For method. I am making a GET call to get back a list. Then I want to take that list and add it to the main list. I have tried addRange which is not thread safe, and will return the wrong data in the list. I have also tried to use ConcurrentBag which also does not get the right data. When I say does not get the right data I mean some of the data in the lists is either repeating or gets over written.

Here is my code(updated):

```
var thisLock = new Object();
var list = new List<Person>();
Parallel.For(1, 10, x =>
{
    request.Page = x;
    response = Get(request); // call to client
    lock(thisLock)
    {
        list.AddRange(response);
    }
}
```

Any other ideas besides addRange or ConcurrentBag

Comment: locking around list. There are other mechanisms but this one is simplest, as adding to the list is not likely the major performance bottleneck in the code.

Comment: Why not just lock the list?

Comment: As @Rotem intimated, you need to lock the list when adding to it. Concurrentbag should deal with that. What do you mean doesn't get the right data?

Comment: when I lock the main list will only mess up one call. Meaning the data in one part of the main list will be over written.

Comment: @Beastwood that's not the correct way to `lock`, you should define a specific locking object instead. Regardless, a `ConcurrentBag<T>` is the recommended collection for what you are trying to do. The fact that your data is "duplicated" suggests to me that your server is returning duplicate data rather than the code somehow duplicating it.

Comment: It is meant to get back 300 persons. It will get the correct number (300) but it will have some repeating. After it threads I will do a none threading list and then compare the two. And the threaded list will be the same number but be missing some data that is in the none threaded list

Comment: @James Yeah I rushed through the locking I need to do some research on how to do that. But I was thinking that the server might be returning the wrong data, but I didn't know that was possible if I was passing in the page in which to get data

Comment: @Beastwood If it's still incorrect, the problem is definitely on your server. Scratch that, see James' answer.

Comment: @Rotem Thank you. And thanks for the quick responses everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am making a few assumptions here, but it would appear that your problem is the fact that your `request`/`response` variables are not scoped within the `Parallel.For` call.

The problem is you make a (presumably) synchronous `Get` call which updates the `response` variable but given you have X threads all working with that very same response if that gets updated at any given point i.e. whilst another thread is adding it to the list, then that is going to very well lead to duplicate data.

Same goes for the `request`, you have an obvious race condition meaning that when one thread changes the `request.Page` and another thread is *just* about to pull the data then you are effectively pulling the same page across various threads.

The solution is simple, create your `request`/`response` objects locally

```
var list = new ConcurrentBag<T>();
Parallel.For(1, 10, x =>
{
    var request = // create new request;
    request.Page = x;
    var response = Get(request); // call to client
    foreach (var item in response) {
        list.Add(item); // add it main list
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 This is most likely it, I can't believe I missed it.

Comment: There is no AddRange for ConcurrentBag. Should I just do a loop to add each one individually

Comment: @James Thanks for the help. I actually also had to lock with the ConcurrentBag for some reason to get it to work. And then it still only works about 75% of the time.

Comment: @Beastwood you definitely shouldn't need to lock if you are using `ConcurrentBag<T>`... what do you mean it only works 75% of the time? Are you re-creating both the request & response in each thread as suggested?

Comment: @James I think I might have fixed it. I about to run a lot of tests, but I think I made a dumb mistake. I declared a new request, but i had one declared above, and I just said var newResponse = resonse. And as you can tell I am not that good at programming(YET), but I could be wrong but by doing that I was still pointing at the same object in memory so now I made a brand new request

Answer (score 0):

This is a good candidate for PLINQ. You can then use `SelectMany` for flattening the sequences.

```
var list = ParallelEnumerable.Range(1, 10).SelectMany(x =>
{
    var request = // create new request;
    request.Page = x;
    response = Get(request); // call to client
    return response;
}).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks for the alternative. I tried this way and it worked, but it was a little slower.