# How to use parallel.for to add item to list

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel.for

I came from [Threading with Parallel.For Adding Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24165036/threading-with-parallel-for-adding-lists) . For the example in the link two threads are used to call `Parallel.Invoke` which is still slow so I'd like to do some multi-threading inside the loop assuming i do not care the order items are added.
But the `parallel.for` did not work as expecetd and gives indexoutofRange exception.
Someone plz help?

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var dict1 = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    var dict2 = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    Stopwatch s = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    Parallel.Invoke(() => FillDictionary(dict1, 10000000), () => FillDictionary(dict2, 10000000));
    //FillDictionary(dict1, 10000000);
    //FillDictionary(dict2, 10000000);
    Console.WriteLine("test");
    Console.WriteLine(s.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
private static void FillDictionary(Dictionary<int, string> toFill, int itemCount)
{
    //for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
        //toFill.Add(i, "test" + i);
    Parallel.For(0, itemCount, (i) => toFill.Add(i, "test" + i));    
}
```

Comment: actually i thought maybe using parallel.for is not thread safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Dictionary` is not [thread safe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety).Use [`ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: It works now. One more thing,given my example to iterate 2*10 million loops it throws outofMemory exception. why it happened?

Comment: because you don't have enough memory (RAM)

Comment: I don't think so. I have 4*8gb memory and only used one third of it.

Comment: OutOfMemoryException doesn't mean you have run out of RAM, [it means you have run out of virtual address space]. For 32-bit processes that means you're limited to 2 GB of memory. You might want to try to run your code as a 64-bit process instead.

Comment: And here's the link that I was supposed to be in the above comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory.aspx.